# broadcast message to all online users jsp ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am trying to broadcast a message entered by an admin to be visible to online users as a pop up. i am using ajax to make a call to database with a time interval like the code below. This code runs for each and every online users and returns message if the message_Flag is 1  in the database

```
setInterval( function() 
{
   getChatText(); 
  }, 5000);}


function getChatText() {

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/easyoffice/commonAjax.do",
            data : "method=" + "getMessages",
            success : function(responseText) {
                if (responseText.trim() != ''){   

                     $("#dialog-message").html(responseText);
                    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        draggable: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        position: ['center'],
                        show: 'blind',
                        hide: 'blind',
                        width: 400,
                        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
                        buttons: {
                            "I've read and understand this": function() {
                                      $(this).dialog("close");

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }


            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }

        });
    }
```

This is working correctly , but being a webapp with a lot of users , this causes a performance  drop. I've heard websockets doesn't support Broadcasting. Is there any alternative .??   Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you can go for jabbered server. i.e Openfire